# Replacing the value of a django template variable with another variable calculated in javascript

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have a variable in django template {{ activity.time }}. But I want to replace its value with another variable (localtime) whose value is calculated in javascript.

i.e. I want to assign the value of localtime to {{ activity.time }}

How can i achieve it?

Comment: Do you want to do this client side or on the server?

Comment: @HåkenLid client side

Comment: Then you will not use django templates. Just use something like `<span class="local-time"></span>` and insert the content with jQuery or plain javascript.

Comment: That is what i did right now, but i wanted to use the calculated time with "timesince" i.e. {{ activity.time|timesince }}

Comment: Django template code and filters are executed server side, so they can't work on values that only exist on the users machine. There are javascript plugins that does pretty much the same thing as `timesince`, but client side.  Here's the first one I found with google http://timeago.yarp.com/

Comment: this has nothing to do with django

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the template variable's value to a JS variable:

```
<script>
    var activityTime = '{{ activity.time }}';
    // Now modify `activityTime` however you like
</script>
```